# UI test automation tools for Windows Phone 8 metro apps?

Tags: test-automation-framework

Is there any UI test automation tool or framework exist that can automate Windows Phone 8 metro app?

Answer (score 1):

I must recommend [Perfectomobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/automated_testing.html). You test on real devices and they do have them all.

I havn't used it in my project (yet), but those that have do really recommend it.

Comment: Took a look at the site out of curiosity.  They unfortunately only have 3 Windows Phone devices, all C900's, which won't run Windows Phone 8.  I can see this service being possibly useful for other OS's however.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Automation APIs (UIAutomation) is a robust framework for automating Windows Phone 8 apps. For more information see [Automating the testing of Windows 8 Apps](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031151906/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx)

Comment: Copied from the same article:

Note about testing on Windows RT

Before we dive into the automation topics, we wanted to make a quick note about testing on Windows RT. You can’t build or port x86/64 processes to run on Windows RT. Thus, all the tools and technologies discussed in the rest of this post do not apply for testing on Windows RT. We recommend that you use Visual Studio to test on Windows RT.

Comment: Windows RT is currently in use on the Surface using the ARM chipset. The question was about automating tests on Windows Phone platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[Winium.StoreApps](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps)** framework.

> It's
>
> - free & open-source
> - actively developed & supported
> - supports many programming languages
> - based on Selenium
> - scalable

Also there are official **[Coded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747198.aspx)** tools from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Experitest's seetest](http://experitest.com/), I'm not sure that their version for Windows phone 8 is officially out, but AFAIK is on the way and they did a good job automating Android.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, you can have a look at SIKULI, it is not a Windows Phone 8 testing tool, but it is a tool for UI testing. Here a list of videos http://www.sikuli.org/testing.html (it doesn't work on real device)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mark Chamberlain from Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/86484773-22f1-4b4a-9355-d1a61f77d912/):

> There isn't a built in mechanism enabling you to programmatically
>   mimic touch, tap, gestures, etc.
>
> You would need to build such simulation into your app, for example if
>   you have a UI element's Tap event handler in your code, your UI tap
>   simulator could directly call that event handler.

However, there is now a simple UI Test project on MSFT, with demonstration of how to write one using [the Automation Peer classes](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Simple-UI-Test-for-Windows-dc0573a9).

Finally, Justin Angel, a dev with a blog on this subject has a piece and example on how one might achieve this [over on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420733/connect-to-windows-phone-8-using-console-application).